# What is exactly the meaning of "=>" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is exactly the meaning of "=>" in javascript?
it is used here for example.
https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-gmail/blob/master/scripts/app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=>` called **Arrow Function**

> An arrow function expression (also known as fat arrow function) has a
>   shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds
>   the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target). Arrow functions are always anonymous.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions